# Digital Signing/Decrypting with asymmetric key in medium trust .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, digital-signature, medium-trust

I have some files which I would like to sign digitally with my own certificate in ASP:NET. In 3.5 .NET (medium trust) I managed to do this, but when switching to .NET 4.0 in medium trust I have the System.Security exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type &#39;System.Security.Permissions.KeyContainerPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089&#39; failed.
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
```

My code is:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
            try
            {
                certificate = new X509Certificate2(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + licenceFile, licenceFilePass, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                if (certificate == null)
                    throw new Exception("The certificate is null!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception += "X509Certificate2 fail! Did not get certificate " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + licenceFile;
                exception += FormatException(ex);
                goto SetError;
            }

            RSACryptoServiceProvider myRSASigner = null;

            try
            {
                myRSASigner = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

                if (myRSASigner == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No valid cert was found");
                }


                    doc = SignXmlFile(doc, myRSASigner);

            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exception += "SignXmlFile failed";
                    exception += FormatException(ex);
                    goto SetError;
                }
```

The error occurs when I try to extract the PrivateKey of my own locally stored license file:

```
myRSASigner = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

I understand that I am missing the KeyContainerPermission, but for my own certificate?
Unfortunatly, I also decrypt with another certificate and of course the same problem appears....

I can't raise the trust level, because the website is on a hosted server. I also doubt that I can convince my provider to install my own assembly in the GAC to do this...